# O Doctrine ORM 2 não tem suporte para trabalhar com VIEWS?

Tags: php, doctrine, doctrine-2

Criei uma *View* no banco de dados e agora preciso usa-la no sistema, porém eu não consigo usa-la, pois o *Doctrine* à reconhece como uma tabela, aparece o seguinte erro:

```
Type: Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\Mysqli\MysqliException
Message: Table 'empresa.view_usuario' doesn't exist
File: /var/www/projeto/sistema/third_party/composer/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Driver/Mysqli/MysqliStatement.php
Line: 94
```

Eu fiz os seguintes passsos:

- Criei a view no banco de dados
- Criei a Entidade como ReadOnly
- Criei a DAO e nada funcionou sempre retorna esse erro

Existe algum jeito de usar views no *Doctrine* ?

Comment: O erro esta dizendo que no *Banco de Dados* `empresa` não existe a tabela `view_usuario`

Comment: Sim, mas isso não é uma tabela é uma view, eu procurei alguns exemplos na internet e e tentei fazer a entidade ai, só que sempre da esse erro, no caso eu nem precisaria da entidade só preciso consultar a view e pegar os dados.

Comment: Mas a tabela existe ? Se não existir não vai funcionar.

Comment: Não existe, o que existe é uma view. Mas não tem jeito de eu consultar essa view usando o doctrine ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Desculpe tinha esquecido de colocar a view como readOnly,depois que coloquei funcionou tudo beleza.